# Keycloak-admin-client - turn off logging

Tags: java, logging, jboss, client, keycloak

While using `keycloak-admin-client` v.3.4.3 final with Java  I am having difficulty with disabling default `DEBUG` logging when a new `keycloak` instance connection is set.

Basically in application output I get log output for :

> DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 
>   DEBUG org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers

I would appreciate any suggestions. Since this is an external library I am not quite sure how can I use `log4j.properties` to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you can add logback.xml to your resources directory if you are using maven.
The example below sets root logging to error and also give examples of setting specific packages to different levels.
You can use this to tailor it to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="some.custom.path" level="debug" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="error" />

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```